# What does bootstrap mean when it says collapse?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am learning bootstrap on [Bootstrap's site](http://getbootstrap.com) 
It say's about navbars:

> Navbars are responsive meta components that serve as navigation
>   headers for your application or site. They begin collapsed (and are
>   toggleable) in mobile views and become horizontal as the available
>   viewport width increases.

Here is the

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
      </form>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

The problem is i can't understand what is collapse and why should one use them?

Comment: The best way to sort things like that out are to *play with it*.  Remove the `collapse` class.  What happens? What happens when you put it back in? (Tip: It's telling bootstrap that the contents of that div should *collapse* when the space is small enough that it doesn't fit).

Comment: That's not entirely true, @cale_b. Bootstrap documentation assumes you already understand its responsiveness, and even if you did the behavior is not entirely consistent for each element of the layout.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It means that the inline menu will become a drop down menu when the viewport size is not wide enough to display all the items.

Inline menu:

[image]

Collapsed menu:

[image]

Bootstrap shows that drop down menu with a button in the right-top corner. You'll have to click on it to see the available menu items.